# Removing/hiding all boot screens

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

DISCLAIMER: I'm new to Ubuntu (18.04 - no dual boot).

I'd like to remove all colored screens after booting and turning off (while not seeing any code run on the screen) - also changing the login screen background to black (not lock screen).
After the manufacturer logo there's a second long purple screen. Then the screen totally turns off and after a second black screen the ubuntu loading screen shows up. Finally I can log in.
I searched for many questions and there are some thing I tried:

- Editing GRUB file - removing quiet splash/replacing to only quiet (I remember I could remove the splash, but then there was the code running on screen, so I'd like to change the color to black) - then updating grub
- Changing plymouth theme file to change the Window.SetBackgroundTop(Bottom)Color to (0,0,0) - this one hasn't changed anything I guess
- Creating a new plymouth theme and using a total black 1920x1080 image as background - haven't noticed any change, even tho the theme was used as alternative

Some of these changes messed with plymouth's Reboot and Power Off services and couldn't solve it, so I had to reinstall Ubuntu. I hasn't tried anything yet.

Is the first purple screen GRUB and the booting plymouth? I'm not sure..

Comment: Yes. There are 3 screens with purple: after manufacturer logo, then after black screen the ubuntu loading screen, third being the login screen. I'd like all of them black

Comment: Clean install, haven't touched any config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve the requirements in the Question for default Ubuntu 18.04

need to edit the below files:

1. for changing grub color: `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.grub`
2. for plymouth color: `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`
3. for login-screen background color: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css`

`ubuntu-logo.grub` my file content. replace the values to `0,0,0,0;` for black

```
if background_color 66,48,228,0.5; then
  clear
fi
```

`ubuntu-logo.script` some of my file content. replace the values to `(0, 0, 0);` for black

```
Window.SetBackgroundTopColor (0.16, 0.00, 0.12);     # Nice colour on top of the screen fading to
Window.SetBackgroundBottomColor (0, 1.02, 1.02);  # an equally nice colour on the bottom
```

`ubuntu.css` my file edited content at around line number 1814

`#lockDialogGroup {
  background-color: #000000; }`

after editing the files, save & close all files..

then run `sudo update-grub`

Reboot to see the change.