# Why is my GRUB menu background in ubuntu 18.04 black?

Tags: boot, grub2, plymouth

I installed some additional desktop environments in ubuntu 18.04, and I don't know if this has something to do with it, but around the time installing these desktop environments, I discovered that my boot screen was not the standard ubuntu one, rather the ubuntu budgie boot theme. I tried to fix it, but I messed up some plymouth related stuff, so I ended up reinstalling the default plymouth theme for ubuntu 18.04.

Now I discovered that my grub menu background is black, not the standard "ubuntu-purple", and I don't know if it has something to do with the plymouth related stuff, but anyways, the question is: "how can I fix the grub menu back to the defaults?".

My GRUB menu version is 2.02 (output of `grub-install --version` is
`grub-install (GRUB) 2.02-2ubuntu8.13`), and I don't know if this is the standard version of GRUB in ubuntu 18.04, so that is another question I'm wondering about.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: The way you play around caused it..and definetly it is of plymouth..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1127217/739431 from this link.. Concentrate on ubuntu-logo.grub or similar files related with your plymouth themes..

Comment: I read the "How to change the purple background color in grub?" question once before I asked this question, but not very carefully. I now read it more carefully, and found the solution of the problem: in the directory  `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/`, and in the file named "default.grub", the problem was sitting:

Comment: I read in the "How to change the purple background color in grub?" question that there must be a space character between the color value and the semicolon, and I just had to put in a space character there, and then the problem was fixed! Thank you all for the answers!

Comment: After applying your changes, remember to run the `sudo update-grub` command!