# Disable purple screen at gnome start for kiosk app in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gdm, plymouth, kiosk

I've been trying to minimize an Ubuntu 18.04 image for a kiosk application.

during the boot an empty purple screen appears for a second then system goes into my application.
[[gif]Purple screen appearing after kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd2Yy.gif)

[[img]Purple screen appearing after kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBUcg.png)

All I need to do is to make this purple screen disappear (or make it black).

Things I've tried:

- removing plymouth: `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove plymouth`
- changing the background color of **#lockDialogGroup** in gdm3.css

but they both didn't work.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: have you gone through this https://askubuntu.com/a/1127217/739431

Comment: Yes, I've tried this but none of them worked unfortunately.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1127236/739431